# How to synch log_every_n_steps with save_summaries_secs in TensorFlow slim

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I am new to using TF Slim for my training:

```
slim.learning.train(
    train_op,
    FLAGS.log_dir,
    log_every_n_steps=1,
    number_of_steps=FLAGS.max_steps,
    save_summaries_secs=1)
```

My log looks like:

```
...
INFO:tensorflow:global step 93: loss = 0.0425 (0.25 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 94: loss = 0.0460 (0.39 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 95: loss = 0.0416 (0.25 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 96: loss = 0.0480 (0.25 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 97: loss = 0.0424 (0.27 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 98: loss = 0.0487 (0.30 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 99: loss = 0.0481 (0.26 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 100: loss = 0.0390 (0.25 sec/step)
```

And my summaries look like:

```
...
ScalarEvent(wall_time=1496698866.417926, step=93L, value=0.04702041298151016)
ScalarEvent(wall_time=1496698867.504077, step=97L, value=0.0489736944437027)
ScalarEvent(wall_time=1496698868.423048, step=100L, value=0.04433770477771759)
ScalarEvent(wall_time=1496698869.449098, step=100L, value=0.035440053790807724)
```

Why are the numbers for the same time step different? How do I get my summaries to have the same numbers as my log?

Comment: The reason they're different is that they're computed on different mini-batches of data. Getting them to match up would likely mean computing them together rather than asynchronously (as the Supervisor does). Is there a reason you need them to match up?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why are they computed on different mini-batches of data? Shouldn't the same data batch match up against the same global step? I don't need them to match up but I was just confused.

Comment: It would be possible to seed mini-batching based on the global step, although in practice it would be hard to do with queues ([input iterators](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data) may make this better eventually) and I've never seen an input pipeline that does it. Instead, dequeues shuffle based on the items available when the dequeue happens; since the [summary writer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py#L977) dequeues in a separate graph invocation (`run()`), it gets a different mini-batch.